# Java and MySQL - "Unrecognized statement"

Tags: java, mysql

```
package main.java;

import java.sql.*;

public class SQLSetup {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "Halli";
   static final String PASS = "dragon";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try{
           //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

           //STEP 3: Open a connection
           System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
           System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

           //STEP 4: Execute a query
           System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
           stmt = conn.createStatement();

           String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION " +
                   "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                   " first VARCHAR(255), " +
                   " last VARCHAR(255), " +
                   " age INTEGER, " +
                   " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
           System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
       }catch(SQLException se){
           //Handle errors for JDBC
           se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){
           //Handle errors for Class.forName
           e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
           //finally block used to close resources
           try{
               if(stmt!=null)
                   conn.close();
           }catch(SQLException se){
           }// do nothing
           try{
               if(conn!=null)
                   conn.close();
           }catch(SQLException se){
               se.printStackTrace();
           }//end finally try
       }//end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
   }
}
```

Why is CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION giving me the error "Unrecognized statement"? I am using Intellij, Java 13 and Maven and MySQL server.

This is just something to get my question through since the template is complaining about me not giving enough details and a lot of code, but I am not sure what more to say about the problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the SQL statement. I just ran it; see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c354e The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Try to use "stable" versions of Java such as Java 8, Java 11, Java 14, etc. (every three numbers), not unstable ones like Java 13.

Answer (score 0):

It did not even occur to me that I could run the code with Intellij giving me a red error on this, but it did not matter - I tried to run the code and Voila - it created a table, even with this error message.